# Unity Google Mobile Ads on Android Build Failure : com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException : org.gradle.process.internal.exectException

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, admob

My game was working fine and all of a sudden am getting this error popup:
 [image]

and this console error :

```
    `CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity2017.2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleDebug"

stderr[
C:\Projects\UpJump\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\DevTools\sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
]
stdout[
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location 'D:\DevTools\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'D:\DevTools\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
Observed package id 'build-tools;18.0.1' in inconsistent location 'D:\DevTools\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3' (Expected 'D:\DevTools\sdk\build-tools\18.0.1')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-17;default;mips' in inconsistent location 'D:\DevTools\sdk\system-images\android-17\mips' (Expected 'D:\DevTools\sdk\system-images\android-17\default\mips')
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
```

Am not sure what error to focus with, i did some research and some people suggesting updating the SDK other said the updates are what causes this, i ended up installing Android studio and using its SDK path in unity, also installed Android-p (preview) sdk, the error changed to this :

[image]

And the error code :

```
stderr[
C:\Projects\UpJump\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\DevTools\New_SDK\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any idea please ?

**EDIT :** 
Adding Build.gradle

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'cardview-v7-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'onesignal-unity', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'percent-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'unity-ads', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':answers')
    compile project(':beta')
    compile project(':crashlytics')
    compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
    compile project(':fabric')
    compile project(':fabric-init')
    compile project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')
    compile project(':OneSignalConfig')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 27
        applicationId 'com.chorusworldwide.upjump'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'

        }
    }

}
```

thank you

Comment: Share your build.gradle

Comment: What other plugins are you using besides Unity Google Mobile Ads?

Comment: @Shaman check the full plugin list here : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/630 (StackOverflow said my post is mostly code and i need to write more description because of how long the list was, but mainly : GMobAds with Vungle, Unity and Nend, GameAnalytics, OneSignal, Fabric, Crashlytics)

Comment: @W0rmH0le where to find that ?

Comment: @W0rmH0le nvm, i exported the unity project and added build.gradle to the main thread, check the update plz

Comment: What makes you think Unity Google Mobile Ads is causing this error?

Comment: cause it's the last plugin i've been messing with, adding/removing adapters, etc...

Comment: In Android Studio, in your  `build.gradle` file, comment the following line:  `compile project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')`, and try to compile.

Comment: it's giving me this error : https://i.imgur.com/eeSaKko.png

Comment: Update : I am 90% sure that its related to the Android SDK tool now, i rolled back the project to a version that used to build fine, and am still getting the error (2nd image pop in the original post)

Comment: Yes i confirm : its something about not found a "dialogCornerRadius"